# Soluition of Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solution of Riccati equation:

$y' -y + y^2 e^x + 5e^{-x} = 0 , y(0) = \pi $

My work:

A Riccati equation of the form $y' + py + q y^2 = r $ can be transformed to second order ODE as follows.

$u''+\left ( p - \dfrac{q'}{q} \right ) u' -rq u =0 $

Therefore,

$p = -1 $, $q = e^x $, $r = -5 e^{-x}$

$u''+\left ( -1 - \dfrac{(e^{x})'}{e^x} \right ) u' + 5u =0 $

$u''+\left ( -1 -1 \right ) u' + 5u =0 $

$u''- 2u' + 5u =0 $

The auxillary equation is

$ k^2 -2k +5  = 0 $

$k = \dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-20}}{2}$

$k = 1 \pm 2 i$

Therefore, the solution is,

$u(x) = e^{x} (C_1 \cos (2x) + C_2 \sin (2x))$

How to find the solution for y? Kindly advise.

Comment: Isn't $ \frac{ q'}{q}=1 $ since $ q=e^x$.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the catch. I arrived the solution for u(x). How to find the solution for y(x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y' -y + y^2 e^x + 5e^{-x} = 0 $$
$$y(0) = \pi$$
Substitute:
$$y=e^{-x}\dfrac {u'}u$$
Then the differential equation becomes:
$$u''-2u'+5u=0$$
It's easy to find $y$ if you know $u$.

Note that the DE is also separable:
$$y' -y + y^2 e^x + 5e^{-x} = 0$$
Multiply the DE by $\dfrac {e^{-x}}{y^2}$:
$$ \left (\dfrac  {e^{-x}}{y} \right )' + 1+ 5 \left ( \dfrac  {e^{-x}}{y} \right)^2 = 0$$
$$w'+1+5w^2=0$$
It's easy to integrate.

Comment: Lovely! What a flawless explanation. Thanks a million :)

Comment: You are welcome @Aruha